# Vim substitution with multiple pattern with OR operator and visual mode selected text

Tags: vim, sed, replace, substitution

I have :

```
RT_T_up2 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up2)
RT_T_dw2 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw2)
RT_T_up3 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up3)
RT_T_dw3 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw3)
RT_T_up4 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up4)
RT_T_dw4 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw4)
```

and I would like to put a "1" in front of up and dw, i.e to get :

```
RT_T_up12 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up12)
RT_T_dw12 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw12)
RT_T_up13 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up13)
RT_T_dw13 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw13)
RT_T_up14 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up14)
RT_T_dw14 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw14)
```

The original text was selected with visual mode into vim.

I tried to do :

```
:'<,'>s:up\([2-4]\):up1\1:e |  s:dw\([2-4]\):dw1\1:e
```

but it replaces only up the first `up` by giving :

```
RT_T_up12 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up2)
RT_T_dw2 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw2)
RT_T_up13 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up3)
RT_T_dw3 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw3)
RT_T_up14 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_up4)
RT_T_dw4 = CubicSpline(z_alot, RT_tab_dw4)
```

How can I insert a "`1`" just after each `up` and `dw` pattern ?

Comment: I think you need to add the g flag to the substitution

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  or [vim.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use nested grouping with the alternation operator**

I created sub-expression groups for `up` and `dw` and nested them together with the alternation operator, `\|`.

As @wobr has indicated, use the `g` flag to perform the substitution for all occurences on a given line. You can read up about the substitution flags here, `:help :s_flags`.

I reference only sub-exrpession groups `\1` and `\4` in my replacement string:

```
'<,'>s/\(\(up\)\|\(dw\)\)\([2-4]\)/\11\4/ge
```

The `e` flag just prevents an error message for search pattern failures. Most people do not mind the error message.

---

**How to properly reference sub-expression groups**

Going from left to right in your pattern, count the starting parenthesis, `(`. The count will be the sub-expression's reference number:

[image: sub-expression reference counting]

This is alluded to in `:help pattern`.

---

Here is a before and after look of this command:

[image]

Afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Just a question : why the pattern `\([2-4]\)` is considered as 4th group when we print with `\4` and not `\3`,  i.e I don't understand why  it is not 3th group, so we would rather write : `'<,'>s/\(\(up\)\|\(dw\)\)\([2-4]\)/\11\3/ge` . By the way, what does flag `e` at the  end represent and do ? Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 I updated the answer to respond to your question on referencing sub-expressions (groups).

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```
:%s/\v(up|dw)/\11/g

\v .................... very magic
(up|dw) ............... up or dw
\1 .................... reinserts the regex group
1  .................... here our desired 1
```

Comment: Magic does make it look nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, where the entries are all aligned to the same column and you want to apply the same modification ("insert 1") to all of them, you could also use Visual block mode to accomplish this task.

Execute the following sequence of commands:

- `f2`: Move cursor to character `2` in the first line.
- `<C-V>`: Enter Visual Block mode.
- `5j`: Extend the selection to the next 5 lines, covering all the entries you want to modify.
- `I1<Esc>`: Insert "1" before the Visual Block. As you press the Escape key, all other lines will receive the same modification.
- `2f2`: Move cursor to the last "2" in the first line.
- `.`: Repeat. That will insert "1" again, in the column you're in now, on the same number of lines.